# Google Oauth 2 PHP

Tags: php, authentication, oauth, single-sign-on

I am looking for an example of the Google Oauth php for login.  I basically need to get the users email, picture url, google+ url, Full Name.  I have found some online but some of the code they are using has or will be deprecated.

Comment: Hi @user3365353 : [Here](http://www.sanwebe.com/2012/11/login-with-google-api-php) is the exapmle which I have used few days ago and it workes properly. Please give it a try once.

Comment: this is using the "OAuth 2.0 login(early version)" which is said to be deprecated in september this year. https://developers.google.com/+/api/auth-migration#timetable

Answer (score 0):

Please check below link to integrate Google OAuth 2 login to your web applications using php.

http://www.smarttutorials.net/login-with-google-oauth-2-using-php-and-mysql/

Please download php SDK from following link.

https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client[enter link description here](https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client)

To integrate Google OAuth you client ID and Client Secret, please go through following URL and create it.

https://code.google.com/apis/console